# How to practice openings in Fritz 18

Tags: opening, training

Is there any way in Fritz 18 to choose a specific opening from a list of openings and play against the computer? I can do this on chess.com and Lucas chess. I want something similar. How do I have a ready set of openings. Do I have to download something called an opening book? Which tab must I go to?

Comment: Can't you just set up the starting position and play from there?